# Command finger doesn't display .plan

Tags: ubuntu, users, finger

If I have a .plan but finger doesn't show it, does that mean that something is wrong with my system?

```
 uname -a
Linux share-02.csc.kth.se 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 17:54:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

output of `$ ls -dl ~ ~/.plan`

```
drwxr-xr-x 83 nik nogroup 10240 May  4 14:03 /home/n/i/nik
lrwxr-xr-x  1 nik default    12 Nov 24  2015 /home/n/i/nik/.plan -> Public/.plan
```

finger doesn't work even though I have a .plan:

```
$ cat .plan 
The back-up plan.

                                                ########
                                             ##############
                                           ###################
                                          #####################
                                          ######################
           #####                         #######################
        ###########                      ########################
      ###############                    ########################
     ################                    ########################
    ###################                  ########################
   #####################                 ########################
  ######################                  #######################
  #######################                 ######################
 ########################     #################################
 ########################   ##################################
 ######################### ###########       #################
 ###################################   ####   ############
 ###########################     ###  #    #  ########
  ########################   ###  ##        #  #####
   ######################   #      #           ######
   ######################  #           ####     ######
    ####################   #  #####   #    #    ######
     ############## ####     #     # #      #   #######
       ##########  #####    #      # #      #   #######
         ######   ######    #       # # ###  #  #######
                  ######    #   ##### ###### #  #######
                  #######    # ######  ######   #######
                  ########   #  #####  ###### ###      ##
                   #######    ################          #
                   ########    #### ########   #         #
                   ########    #   ##########            #
                   #####   ## ##  ###########  ###       #
                   #         #    ###########   # #     #
                  #               ##########    #  #    #
                  #         ##      ########    #       #
                  #        ##       ######    #       #
                   #      #  #               ##      #
                   #          #           ####   # ##
                    #          ##      #######  ###
                     ##          #########  ##  ##
                      #      #     ####     #  #
                        ########    #  #   #  #
                           ######    ######  ####
                       #############      ########
                   ################################
                 ########  ########################
                ########  ##########################
               ########  ############################
               ######               #################
               #####                   ###############
                ###                    ################
                ###   ####     ###        ### #########
                 #   ######   #####         #  #########
                 #   ######  ######         # #########
                #   ######  #######          ##########
                #   ######  #######          #### ####
                #    ####   #######          #########
                #    ###    ######           ########
                 #           ####            ######
                 #                           ###
                 #                          #
                 #                          #
                  #                         #
                  #                          #
                  #                          #
                  #                           #
                  #      #  #                 #
                  #       ## #               #
                   #        ###           ##
                    ####      #      ######
                        ####################
                           ####### #########
                            ####### #########
                             ####### #########
                              ####### ########
                               ####### #######
                                ####### #######
                                 ###### #######
                                 ####### #######
                                # ################
                 ##########      #   ###  ######       ###########
               ##         ###   ###   ##  ######      #           ####
             ##              ##   ##   ##   ####      # #####        ###
            ##                 ##  #   # #          # #                 #
            #                    # #    # #        # #                  #
            #                     # #   #  #      # #                   #
             #                     # #   #       # #                    #
              #                     # #  #      # #                    #
               #                        ##        #                   #
                #                      #  ##                         #
                 ##                    #    ##                      #
                   ##               ###       ##                   #
                     ###############            ##               ##
                                                  #####        ##
                                                       ########



Niklas Rosencrantz
Styrmang 47 a
114 60 Stockholm Sweden
+46 8 661 87 06
+46 70 753 26 37

########################nik@share-02:~$ finger nik
Login: nik                      Name: Niklas Rosencrantz
Directory: /home/n/i/nik                Shell: /bin/bash
On since Thu Jul  6 20:16 (CEST) on pts/7 from 213.89.144.192
   3 seconds idle
No mail.
No Plan.
nik@share-02:~$
```

Comment: Output of `ls -dl ~ ~/.plan` please

Comment: @JeffSchaller I added the output to the question.

Comment: Appears that .plan is a symlink; are the Public and Public/.plan directory/file readable?

Comment: @JeffSchaller AFAIK, yes. `$ cat Public/.plan` outputs correctly.

Comment: `$ ls -al Public/.plan 
-rw-r--r-- 1 nik dip 5569 Sep 12  1999 Public/.plan
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source code for finger as used in Ubuntu](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/bsd-finger/vivid/view/head:/finger/lprint.c#L339) indicates that it will not read a non-regular ~/.plan file (e.g. a symlink, as you have). See the last `if ... return 0` line:

```
static int
show_text(const char *directory, const char *file_name, const char *header)
{
    int ch, lastc = 0, fd;
    FILE *fp;
    struct stat sbuf1, sbuf2;

    snprintf(tbuf, TBUFLEN, "%s/%s", directory, file_name);

    if (lstat(tbuf, &sbuf1) || !S_ISREG(sbuf1.st_mode)) return 0;
```

The show_text function is called on to display the contents of various files, including .plan.

To make your file visible through `finger`, make `.plan` a regular file, not a symlink.

Comment: Cool! It worked.